# Capturing groups inside curly braces

Tags: regex

I need a capturing group that will return me `inner1:` and `inner2:` between curly braces but `outter:`.

```
outter: value
{ inner1: value, inner2: value, ... }
```

I tried this one;`\{.*?(\w*\:).*\}` and I only got the first `inner1:`. What kind of pattern should I use in order to return the rest of groups between curly braces?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like JSON syntax. why not just serialize it into a JSON object or a dictionary and extract based on the keys?

Comment: It looks like JSON but it is not and I need a hard-coded regular expression because I have no such option like serializing this codes into a JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to capture `inner1:` and `inner2:`

```
^\{\s*(?:(\w+:)\s*\w+\s*,?\s*)+\s*\}$
```

EDIT: Changed slightly, it shows it captures the values when I use expresso to test it.

Comment: At first glance I thought it would work but apparently it is only capturing the last one, `inner2`, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Updated, I also use Expresso to test, and it captures both.It's the same match, but it should contain multiple values. What language are you running this in?

Comment: It is Python but right now it does not capture any group at all even though it feels right.

Comment: @ErenCAY, it's really strange, I can put captures around EVERYTHING, and it still doesn't show the values from the first capture...strange.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is well-formed json you can use a json parser.

Another way is to use a simple pattern to extract all the content inside curly brackets `{([^}]++)}` and split the result.

a full regex way: (work with an undefined number of key/value)

```
(?>{|\G(?<!\A):[^,}]++,)\s*([^:]++)
```

the result is in the capture group 1

pattern details:

```
(?>            # atomic group: all that can be before the key
    {          # literal: {
  |            # OR
    \G(?<!\A)  # contiguous to a precedent match but not a the start of the string 
    :[^,}]++,  # a : followed by all that is not a , or } followed by a ,
)              # close the atomic group
\s*            # possible spaces
([^:]++)       # capture group 1: all that is not a :
```

example:

```
text = <<EOF
outter: value
{ inner1: value, inner2: value, inner3: val }
EOF

puts text.scan(/(?>{|\G(?<!\A):[^,}]++,)\s*([^:]++)/)
```