# Edit with sed using capturing group of curly braces (windows)

Tags: json, sed

On Windows, I am trying to do an in-place edit of simple JSON files that are malformed. My files look like this, with first object duplicated.

```json
{
  "hello":"there"
}
{
  "hello":"there"
}
```

My goal is to have only one object, and discard the second one.  I should note that the files have linefeeds, as shown here.
End file should look like

```json
{
  "hello":"there"
}
```

I can match the first group using a regexp like `^({.*?}).*`. This is fairly simple.

Seems like a perfect job for sed in-place editing. But apparently no matter what combination of escaping I do in sed, I can't match the brackets. I am using  `(GNU sed) 4.9` patch by Michael M. Builov.

Some results I get:

```
# as per original regexp
sed.exe -E "s,^({.*?}).*,d,g" double.json
     ->  -e expression #1, char 16: Invalid preceding regular expression

# trying to escape paranthesis
sed.exe -E "s,^\({.*?}\).*,d,g" double.json
     ->  -e expression #1, char 18: Invalid content of \{\}

# escaping curly brackets
sed.exe -E "s,^\(\{.*?\}\).*,d,g" double.json
     -> Works, but original file is returned (no match)
```

Is it possible at all on Windows ? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334972/capturing-groups-inside-curly-braces) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21725014/1818059) it seems that Windows for some reason does not like curly brackets with sed.

Note: tested in WSL/Ubuntu, and got same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez 's/((\{[^}]*}).*)\2/\1/' input_file
{
  "hello":"there"
}
```

Comment: this worked with `(GNU sed) 4.5` for Windows, but not the patched version. And it worked *only* if the last object ended with a linefeed. Unfortunately I can't guarantee it will. So not fully there yet. I also need to analyze the expression further - sed is a bit new to me.

Comment: Sorry @MyICQ I have not been able to test it just yet but have made a slight change.

Answer (score 0):

`jq` command line tool is handy to use for JSON values, even on Windows. You can download by [this link](https://customer.precisely.com/s/article/Data360-Analyze-How-to-use-jq-on-Windows-360059947393?language=en_US) as an example.

Then save the command

```
inputs
```

into a file called `double.jq`, and then call from command line by

[Windows key]+ cmd

```
cd to_the_path_where_the_files_reside    
jq -f double.jq <double.json
```

if there are more than two independent objects within the file `double.json` such as

```json
{
  "hello":"there"
}
{
  "hello":"there"
}
{
  "hello":"there"
}
{
  "hello":"there"
}
```

and want to pick the first one only, then convert code of the `double.jq` to

```
[inputs] | unique | .[]
```